# cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) error: (-215) pixels <= (1<<30) in function validateInputImageSize

Tags: opencv

I faced an issue where the pixels are too big and in the documentation: 
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp

It shows that the max pixels is:

```
#define CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PARAMS (50)
#define CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH (1<<20)
#define CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT (1<<20)
#define CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS (1<<30) // 1 Gigapixel
```

And this is the error i obtained:

```
rgb = cv2.imread(XX)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) 
/feedstock_root/build_artefacts/opencv_1520722613778/work/opencv- 
3.4.1/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:74: error: (-215) pixels <= (1<<30) 
in function validateInputImageSize
```

Is there any work around this?

Thank you!

Comment: By "pixels are too big" do you mean the image has too many pixels for opencv to handle. What file type and size is your image?

Comment: If your image size is higher than a gigapixel, there's not much you can do about it with OpenCV. Other python libraries like PIL also have [similar limits](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/limits.html). Try splitting your image into smaller chunks using another software.

Comment: @Mick jpg file and its about 33000 pixels

Comment: @Sunreef sure i'll try it thanks!